# Can I update my iPad to 9.3.1?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update

Can I update my iPad if it hasn't been done for a couple of years to 9.3.1? I haven't updated in a long time and it's currently at 7.1.2.

Comment: What model exactly is your iPad?

Comment: There is a list of compatible devices available [here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/10/ios-9-compatibility-supported-devices-list/).

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same as your but I have tried mine just few days back... it's iOS 8 and iPad3.  It was okay but had to be connected to iTunes (USB).

Over the air had problems.
Using non-original cables will also cause issues (my previous experiences).

Just make sure you make a backup as there is a big chance it will fail and you have no choice but to restore from backup which will first update your iPad to the latest OS then re-download the software and data.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your iPad, I think it's no need to update your iPad, although you updated your iPad to latest version,

There may 2 problems:

1. Some new feature of iOS you can't use because of your iPad hardware limited
2. The latest version of iOS will slow down your interact with your iPad

But you still can try it. Actually when you update your iPad the software of apple will tell you whether your device can update.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can, depending upon your iPad model. You can check the iPad compatibility list [here](http://www.ios11guide.com/ios-11-compatibility/).